# magento2 weird issue for There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace

Tags: xampp, magento2

I am facing below issue in my entire installations of M2.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.
```

weird thing is I installed fresh Xampp and set up new M2 instance, then also same issue persists. It started coming suddenly and I have tried all available solutions like setting permissions to folders and trying -vvv option and list command to find exact issue.
till now no success. My whole day wasted in debugging this only and now I am running out of thoughts.
If anyone have ideas?

I am using PHP 5.6 and Magento EE 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Solution :

Solution 1 :Please mention setup_version in your module.xml file. Your module.xml file looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/> 
</config>
```

Solution 2 : You need to give full permission to both var and pub folders recursively.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

if above solution not work then try following link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/magento-2-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error can be seen in the command output: **`php -f bin/magento`**.

This will work for most errors like `There are no commands defined in the "..." namespace.`.

---

A fairly common cause is an error in `xml` files e.g. `VendorName/ModuleName/etc/config.xml`.